# Getting Rpy2 to work with rgdal to spatially subset points

Tags: python, r, gis, rpy2

So I have some R code that already works. This takes a bunch of points from data and spatially subsets against a shapefile in the method of http://robinlovelace.net/r/2014/07/29/clipping-with-r.html.

```
#data is a .csv file with lon lat points
data_points <- SpatialPoints(data)
proj4string(data_points) <- CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0")
data_ll <- spTransform(data_points, CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0"))
melbourne <- readOGR("melbourne_australia.land.coastline","melbourne_australia_land_coast") #this is a shapefile from https://mapzen.com/data/metro-extracts
subset <- data_ll[melbourne,]
```

plot(melbourne)
points(subset)

I'm trying to convert this to the corresponding rpy2 script. So far I have;

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import rpy2.robjects as ro
import rpy2.robjects.numpy2ri
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr
rgdal = importr('rgdal')
base = importr('base')

rpy2.robjects.numpy2ri.activate()
data = pd.read_csv('sim.csv')
data = data.values
coordinates = ro.r['coordinates']
proj4string = ro.r['proj4string']
spTransform = ro.r['spTransform']
readOGR = ro.r['readOGR']
SpatialPoints = ro.r['SpatialPoints']
CRS = ro.r['CRS']
class_r = ro.r['class']

key = CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0")
data_points = SpatialPoints(data, proj4string = key)
data_ll = spTransform(data_points, key)
melbourne = readOGR("melbourne_australia.land.coastline", "melbourne_australia_land_coast")

subset = data_ll[melbourne,]
```

which fails on the last line with the error TypeError: 'RS4' object is not subscriptable. Does anyone have some idea of what is going on?

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is to convert the R code to a function and then import it as a package.

This is the R code:

```
library(rgdal)
library(sp)

#import data
data <- read.csv("sim.csv", header = F)

subset_points <- function(data){
    data_points <- SpatialPoints(data, proj4string=CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0"))
    data_ll <- spTransform(data_points, CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0"))
    sink("/dev/null")  
    melbourne <- readOGR("melbourne_australia.land.coastline", "melbourne_australia_land_coast")
    sink()
    subset <- data_ll[melbourne,]

    final <- as.data.frame(subset)
    return(final)
}
```

and this is the Python code:

```
import rpy2.robjects as ro
import rpy2.robjects.numpy2ri
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr

from rpy2.robjects.packages import SignatureTranslatedAnonymousPackage
with open('subset_data.R') as fh:
    rcode = os.linesep.join(fh.readlines())
    subset = SignatureTranslatedAnonymousPackage(rcode, "subset")
rpy2.robjects.numpy2ri.activate()

data = pd.read_csv('sim.csv')
data = data.values
final = subset.subset_points(data)
print(np.array(final).T)
```